# How to get my handleClick to render different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner so please excuse my ignorance. I am posting one component from a larger app that I am building. This component has a handleClick function that changes the state when an image is clicked. When the image is clicked, a new component is rendered. Currently, the same 'new component' is rendered no matter which image is clicked. I'd like the component to be based on which image was clicked.

```
var AllocationDiv = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {clicked: false};
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    this.setState (
    {clicked: true}
    ); 
  },
  render: function () {
    var handleFunc = this.handleClick; //because it wasn't brining this.handleClick into the render function
    var chartMap = pieCharts.map(function(prop){
      return <img onClick={handleFunc} id={prop} src={prop} />;
    }); 
    return (
      <div id='bottomSection'>
          <h2>Select Desired Asset Allocation</h2>
          <div id='pieCharts'>
            <table>
              <tr>{pieHeadMap}</tr>
            </table>
              <div>
                {chartMap}
                  <div id='test'>  
                    {this.state.clicked ? <TestComponent /> : null}
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

var chartMap renders three images. Assuming I create three unique test components, how would I get them to be rendered depending on which image was clicked? Here is the entire app. I know the whole thing is a mess atm, but I'm using this as a sandbox to learn through problem-solving. Thanks!
http://codepen.io/sdpercussion/pen/NRQNLv?editors=0010

Comment: Are you saying this code works at all?  Because to me it looks like it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I would do for this.  Instead of having a boolean value for your clicked state, you should have a string.  The string should be the name of the image being clicked. (you need to assign names or ID's or anything to differentiate them)

so.. initial state is:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {clicked:''};
},
```

next your handleClick would have to change and you'd need to pass the image name/Id in to it.

```
handleClick: function(image) {
  this.setState ({
    clicked: image
  }); 
},
```

then, inside your render..

(make sure to `.bind(this)` in your map so you can use the component scope if you want to call your methods. `var self = this;` type workarounds show a misunderstanding of scope)

```
render: function () {

    var chartMap = pieCharts.map(function(prop){
      // pass in your image name to your callback using bind, null value here skips over the scope portion and is what you need
      return <img onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, prop)} id={prop} src={prop} />;
    }.bind(this)); 

    // get the component you want for each specific image and save to a variable for display
    var imgVar = null;
    switch (this.state.image) {
        case 'image1':
            imgVar = <NewComponent />;
            break;
        case 'image2':
            imgVar = <DifferentComponent />;
            break;
    }

    return (
      <div id='bottomSection'>
          <h2>Select Desired Asset Allocation</h2>
          <div id='pieCharts'>
            <table>
              <tr>{pieHeadMap}</tr>
            </table>
              <div>
                {chartMap}
                  <div id='test'>  
                    {imgVar}
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: OK so I think I follow you at least part way through. I like the idea of making the clicked state a string. That way I would pass the image name/id as the state instead of a boolean. however, I think I want a completely different component to render based on which image is clicked, rather than passing it to the same component as a prop. Does this make sense? the new component will be completely different depending on which image is clicked. Lastly, would I accomplish this with something like an if/else if/else type statement to render the correct component based on image id?

Comment: Inside of your render, above the return you could `switch (this.state.image)` and if you know the image names for each component you can update a variable with the component to render and then put that variable in the return of the render.  You could even make your default case assign null to your variable and then you could get rid of that ternary , since React will just not display a null.

Comment: var imgVar = null;
    switch (this.state.image) {
        case 'image1':
            imgVar = <ComponentOne />;
        case 'image2':
            imgVar = <ComponentTwo />;
    }


    // in the return
    {imgVar}

Comment: I took your advice on creating a switch statement and plugged in the image names. I know that as a beginner I need to avoid copy/paste people's answers and learn the concepts. I have made a note to understand why i need .bind and .bind(this) to make my onClick work. For now I have updated my code with your suggestions. However, clicking on any of the images does not render anything. I'm not sure what I've done wrong. http://codepen.io/sdpercussion/pen/NRQNLv?editors=0010#0

Comment: 1. suppose to switch on this.state.clicked not .image.. my bad
2. case statements need a break at the end out of convention unless you need it to fall through.. in this case break it
3. case was looking for a string of the entire prop.. so 'http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/img/pie-sample.png' instead of just a name.. can console.log `this.state.clicked` to see what it's looking for
4. handle click needed the input passed in `function(image)`

I guess 4 things..

Comment: This finally solved all my issues. Thank you for your patience with me. I'm clearly a beginner when I forget things like the break in switch statements.

Comment: No worries.  Give yourself more credit.. at least your making the effort to learn! Keep asking tons of questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dynamic "id" to your `<img>` tag as below. So that based on clicked image you can render a component.

```js
 handleClick: function() {
    //alert(event.target.id);
    if(event.target.id === "2"){
    this.setState (
    {clicked: true}
    ); }
  },
  render: function () {
    var handleFunc = this.handleClick; //because it wasn't brining this.handleClick into the render function
    var count =0;
    var chartMap = pieCharts.map(function(prop){
      count++;
      return <img onClick={handleFunc} id={count+1} src={prop} />;
    }); 
    return (
      <div id='bottomSection'>
          <h2>Select Desired Asset Allocation</h2>
          <div id='pieCharts'>
            <table>
              <tr>{pieHeadMap}</tr>
            </table>
              <div>
                {chartMap}
                  <div id='test'>  
                    {this.state.clicked ? <TestComponent /> : null}
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```